# Run mysql script by batch script

Tags: mysql, batch-file

I've searched for hours, there are many posts or tutorials but I couldn't run my batch script.

on dos prompt this code works fine:

```
-u root -h localhost -p******** siir_07 dumper.sql
```

but this gives error with batch:

```
"c:\program files\mysql\mysql server 5.5\bin\mysql.exe" "-u root -h localhost -p******** siir_07 dumper.sql"
```

the error is:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user ' root -h localhost -p******** siir_07 dumper.s'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Z:\test.bat :

```
Z:\webserver\mysql\bin\mysql.exe -u test -p test < test.sql
```

When I run it from command line, everything is OK. So, try to remove quotes and redirect input using `<`.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use source to execute sql script
for example

```
 mysql -u%DBUSERNAME% -p%USERPASSWD% -D%DBNAME% -e "source something.sql;"
```

Answer (score 1):

you should redirect input from file using `<` and remove extra spaces:

```
mysql -uroot -p*** < dumper.sql
```

I would also suggest putting the username password, and most probabry charset parameters in a separate INI file and use it as follows:

```
 mysql --defaults-extra-file=myconf.ini < dumper.sql
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. i fixed it by removing last two quotes.

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked for me:

```
mysql -u my_username -D my_database -p < test.sql
```

After this I got a prompt to enter my password, I did and everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

it thinks this is your username

```
' root -h localhost -p** siir_07 dumper.s'
```

try changing the quotes around in your batch script

Comment: thanks for your reply. it just outputs mysql help text. i ve seen this before while i was doing trial and error.